# Separate words according to delimeter

Tags: c#, regex, split, delimiter

I have a search box that allows both for searching of content in a table (space delimited) and for searching by a specific field in the table (colon delimited).

The only problem is that these can both exist at the same time.
Examples:

1. Type:Non-Fiction Murder
2. Non ISBN:000000001
3. Fiction ISBN:02 Plane

From example 1, Type is the field name, Non-Fiction is its content and Murder is the content in any field. I am looking for a Regex.Split that puts the field:result into a Dictionary and any other result into an array.

I have managed to make both work on a separate basis but not mixed:

```
var columnSearch_FieldNames = inSearch.ToUpper().Trim().Split(':').Where((x,i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
var columnSearch_FieldContent = inSearch.ToUpper().Trim().Split(':').Where((x, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray();
var adhocSearch_FieldContent = inSearch.ToUpper().Trim().Split(' ');
```

Example 4:- Type:Non-Fiction Murder Non ISBN:000000001 Kill

Example Output:- Dictionary ({Type, Non-Fiction}, {ISBN, 0000001})
                 Array {Murder, Non, Kill}

Comment: *that puts the field:result into a Dictionary and any other result into an array* > I don't get that. Can you shown an example output?

Comment: I don't see why you need regex here. Why not just split on the space first, and then split each result from that using the colon? (By the way, you should not use `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` to achieve case-insensitive search. Use a proper comparison method with a `StringComparison` enum value.)

Comment: done @PatrickHofman. If that is still unclear I will re-phrase.

Comment: @PeterDuniho agreed on ToUpper. I thought there might be a way to make the operation in one go hence the regex split rather than having to parse the split words again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why using `Regex` would be faster. And IMHO, I don't think there's any improvement in the readability or maintainability of the code, using `Regex`. If anything, I think it would be more complicated. But if you really want to use `Regex.Split()`, something like this would work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "Type:Non-Fiction Murder Non ISBN:000000001 Kill", key = null, value = null;
    Dictionary<string, string> namedFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<string> anyField = new List<string>();
    Regex regex = new Regex("( )|(:)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (string field in regex.Split(input))
    {
        switch (field)
        {
            case " ":
                _AddParameter(ref key, ref value, namedFields, anyField);
                break;
            case ":":
                key = value;
                break;
            default:
                value = field;
                break;
        }
    }
    _AddParameter(ref key, ref value, namedFields, anyField);
}

private static void _AddParameter(ref string key, ref string value, Dictionary<string, string> namedFields, List<string> anyField)
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        namedFields.Add(key, value);
        key = null;
    }
    else if (value != null)
    {
        anyField.Add(value);
        value = null;
    }
}
```

Now, if you're willing to just use a plain `Regex` match, instead of using the `Regex.Split()` method, one might argue this is marginally more readable/maintainable:

```
private static void UsingRegex(string input)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> namedFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<string> anyField = new List<string>();
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?:(?<key>[^ ]+):(?<value>[^ ]+))|(?<loneValue>[^ ]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        string key = match.Groups["key"].Value,
            value = match.Groups["value"].Value,
            loneValue = match.Groups["loneValue"].Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            namedFields.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            anyField.Add(loneValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The one at the bottom is exactly what I had in mind and was curios as how it could be built. I thought the Split would automatically put the respective words into appropriate lists. Thanks Peter, well done.

Comment: Hi, if I want an updated version of this regex to include other matches, should I edit my original question? kindly guide me. thank you.

Comment: _"should I edit my original question?"_ -- no, it's inappropriate to edit your question to ask something different. If you want to include other matches, the _first_ step you should take is to attempt to modify your existing solution to accommodate your new requirement. If after trying, you're unable to, post a new question with a good [mcve] that shows what you tried, explain what the code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you weren't able to figure out on your own.

Comment: thanks for that. I actually followed your suggestion and managed myself although my regex knowledge is very limited. this new one should further more put 'fieldValues' enclosed in square brackets in a separate array. (?:(?<dateFieldName>[^ ]+):(?<dateFieldValue>(\\[[^_[]+])+))|(?:(?<anyFieldName>[^ ]+):(?<anyFieldValue>[^ ]+))|(?<anyLoneValue>[^ ]+)

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to forego `Regex` for a good old foreach loop combined with multiple splits, I think this achieves what you're looking for:

```
Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<string> contents = new List<string>();

foreach (var word in main.Split(' '))     //main is a string, e.g. "Type:Non-Fiction Murder Non ISBN:000000001 Kill"
{
    var splitted = word.Split(':');
    if (splitted.Length == 2)
    {
        fields.Add(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
        continue;
    }
    contents.Add(word);
}
```

Basically splits words on space, then on colon to separate them.

If you really want an array of contents rather than `List`, simply do `contents.ToArray()`.

Comment: Yes that does it too. I believe the Regex.Split version would be slightly faster though. I'm up-voting as it is certainly useful. Thank you